# Android store SQLite db row id in custom ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an app that stores three strings in a SQLite db. In another activity I query the DB and populate a custom ListView with the strings. To do this I've implemented a BaseAdapter to manage the layout of the custom ListView.

```
public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ArrayList<DictionaryItem> wordList = new ArrayList<DictionaryItem>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;

    public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<DictionaryItem> wordList) {
        this.wordList = wordList;
        this.context = context;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);    // only context can also be used
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return wordList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return wordList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tvEnglish = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvEnglish);
            holder.tvSpanish = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpanish);
            holder.tvSpanishFilename = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSpanishFilename);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tvEnglish.setText(wordList.get(position).getEnglish());
        holder.tvSpanish.setText(wordList.get(position).getSpanish());
        holder.tvSpanishFilename.setText(wordList.get(position).getSpanishFilename());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvSpanish, tvEnglish, tvSpanishFilename;
    }
}
```

What I would also like to do is store the row_id of the db entry in my ListView then retrieve the row_id if I wish to delete that entry from the database.

I've see posts relating to using setTag but I am not sure how to do this when using a ViewHolder as that method seems to address adding content to views in my layout. I don't consider row_id an item to display in my ListView.

Some insight would be appreciated.

I was working toward that and already have get and set methods to do so. However I'm not sure how to access the row_id when I set the adapter. For example in a ListView onclick, I can recover items in my custom view like:

TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEnglish);

but I don't have any view set for the row_id, so I don't know how to get it.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);
        lvWords = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvWords);
        getDataInList();
        da = new DataAdapter(context, wordList);
        lvWords.setAdapter(da);

....

    private void getDataInList() {
        try {
            ManageDictionary md = new ManageDictionary(context);
            md.open();
            ArrayList<DictionaryItem> ml = md.getArrayData();

            for (int i = 0; i < ml.size(); i++) {
                DictionaryItem di = new DictionaryItem();
                di.setRowId(ml.get(i).getRowId());
                di.setEnglish(ml.get(i).getEnglish());
                di.setSpanish(ml.get(i).getSpanish());
                di.setSpanishFilename(ml.get(i).getSpanishFilename());
                // Add this object into the ArrayList myList
                wordList.add(di);
            }
            md.close();
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your DictionaryItem class add a field of type long and name it **id**
Generate a getter and a setter.
Set the id when you query and then you can later get with getter.

Ok, if I understand this correctly, then here is what you should do.

Delete your wordList ArrayList in activity, since there is no point of having it there because you have the same list in adapter.

Modify your get data list method so it's like this.. no point in using the for loop either.

```
     private void getDataInList() {
            try {
                ManageDictionary md = new ManageDictionary(context);
                md.open();
                da = new DataAdapter(context,  md.getArrayData());
                md.close();
            } catch (Exception e){

            }
       }
```

Now change the wordList variable in your adapter so it's like this

```
public ArrayList<DictionaryItem> wordList = new ArrayList<DictionaryItem>();
```

This way you can have only one arraylist and still can use it in your activity.

Now if you want to remove an item with a specific id from your adapter, you need to search for it. If you know the position of it already, that's even better.

Anyway you need first two methods to remove items. The third one if you need an item with specific id.

```
public void deleteItemWithID(long id){
    int length = wordList.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        if(wordList.get(i).getRowId() == id){
            removeItemAtPostion(i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void removeItemAtPostion(int postion){
    wordList.remove(i);
    notifyDataSetChanged(); //This tells the listview to redraw itself
}

public DictionaryItem findItemById(long id){
    int length = wordList.length();
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i){
        if(wordList.get(i).getRowId() == id){
            return wordList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ok, by row_id you mean the id of xml layout? If so then you can access it like this int i = R.layout.row_layout;

Comment: row_id from the db and set in DictionaryItem, I do not set any xml to this id

Answer (score 1):

Using the ListViews' onclicklister I was able to access my DictionaryItem items  through the parent variable.

```
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
DataAdapter da = (DataAdapter)parent.getAdapter();
String row_id = String.valueOf(da.wordList.get(position).getRowId());
Toast.makeText(Dictionary.this, row_id + " id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```